# What is the best way to supply many arguments to an if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, arguments, statements

I have created a form with several user inputs but have the tedious task of checking whether each individual input is not empty before submission. Is there a quicker way, (such as using arrays perhaps) of listing all arguments to the if statement?

At the moment my code looks like this but if possible I would like it to be more efficient in future, like if I were to add more inputs.

```
<form action="sign-up.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" >
Name:<input type="text" name="name" />
Username:<<input type="text" name="username"  /><br />
Password:<input type="password" name="password1" /><br />
Re-type Password:<input type="password" name="password2"  /><br />
Email:<input type="text" name="email"  />
Address:<input type="text" name="address"  />
Post Code:<input type="text" name="postcode"  />
City:<input type="text" name="city"  />
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="sign up" />
</form>

<?php
if (!empty($_POST['name']) 
&& !empty($_POST['username']) 
&& !empty($_POST['password1']) 
&& !empty($_POST['password2']) 
&& !empty($_POST['email'])   
&& !empty($_POST['address'])
&& !empty($_POST['postcode']) 
&& !empty($_POST['city']) )
{
echo "information has been submitted";
}
else {
echo "please fill in all fields!"
}

?>
```

If you have any suggestions please comment.

Comment: How about in a `loop`?

Comment: How would I use a loop? @Script47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what this will do is loop through the $_POST values and check if they're empty. If one is found to be empty, it will set `$hasErrorOccurred` to true. The `if statement` below will determine if the input check is successful or not.

```
    $hasErrorOccurred = false;

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($_POST[$key])) {
            $hasErrorOccurred = true;

            break;
        }
    }

    if ($hasErrorOccurred) {
        // Your error code here.
    } else {
        // Your successful code here.
    }
```

Reading material:

[`break;`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Comment: This is genius. I did't know you could use the $_POST variable in that way. Thanks a lot. @Script47

Comment: Perhaps storing an array of required field names and checking if all of those names exists in $_POST array map is a better way. If the request comes somewhere other than the given form, those keys might not be in $_POST.

Comment: @slhsen the OP stated he wanted them from `$_POST`.

Comment: Still he should check to make sure required variables are non empty (or perhaps with better sanity checks such as minimum number of characters and existence of non-alpha characters in password fields etc.) But let's say next front end developer deleted or misspelled password fields by mistake, above code wouldn't throw an error.

Comment: @slhsen *But let's say...* how can I predict that? Anyhow that is an assumption and my answer directly fixed the issue the OP had. You cannot start asking questions like *what if X, Y or Z happens?* because that just opens you up to an unknowable amount of things that could potentially go wrong. We are here to answer questions not predict the future. No offence is intended in this comment.

Comment: Well in programming you kind of do that don't you :) You check for possible empty fields, possible missing values etc. I agree your answer fits the question that's why I haven't posted another one. I just thought we might improve it just a little bit ;)

Comment: @slhsen sure in programming you do, but I can't predict that the OP might make a mistake in **his** `HTML` can I? I see where you're coming from, however that's just my thought. Sure if the OP asked for it I would. I generally tend to put extra information in my answers when I feel that it would benefit the OP. However his `HTML` is correct so need to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign variables to each field input, this is how I did it.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

 $$key = $_POST[$key];  //assigns input name to variable with the same name.

    }

if(!empty($$key)) {

//code if all fields are not empty  

}
else {

    echo "Please fill in all fields";

}
```

Comment: I used this so it would assign a variable to the input field with the same name as the key (e.g. $name = $_POST['name'] or                     $username = $_POST['username']) - @Script47

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I tried to describe on comments to Script47's answer so I can clarify my point a little bit better:

```
$requiredFields = ['name','username','password1','password2'];
foreach ($requiredFields as $field) {
    if (!array_key_exists($field, $_POST) || empty($_POST[$field])) {
        displayMissingFieldAlert($field);
    }
}
// do the submit etc.
...
```

This way you can catch if a field is somehow forgotten, misspelled or left out of the submission.

Comment: I also like this way, and I see what you mean about sanity checks. What does the `displayMissingFieldAlert` function do? @slhsen

Comment: I wrote it as a placeholder for the operations when a field is missing or empty. You have to implement that function to do whatever is required in that case. Like displaying an error about the missing field etc. Nice thing about it is that you can display name of the missing parameter to user or highlight it on the html form so user knows where did s/he made a mistake.

Comment: Ahh right I see, this is looking more like what i want to obtain. thank you so much @slhsen

Comment: also is there meant to be an 's' on the end of `!array_key_exist` because I tried running the code but a fatal error occurred.   @slhsen