# Inform a user they have missed a specific input field in a form

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to create a form where if a user doesn't enter information into a specific input then on submission of the form, the user is alerted to fill in that input field only (e.g. "Please enter a username").

Currently I have a **foreach loop** that loops through each input field of the form and assigns a variable with the same name as the field (i.e. $name = $_POST['name']).

What would I implement in my code so I could check each individual input field is empty or not and tell the user this, but keep the code to a bare minimal?

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

     $$key = $_POST[$key];  //assigns variable to input.

    }

if(!empty($$key)) {

//code if all fields are not empty  

}
else {

    echo "Please fill in all fields";

}
```

Comment: funny, you posted that as an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31952066/

Comment: @Fred-ii- that pizzza here yet ?

Comment: @Dagon No, the swindler that he is. I'm hungry here!!

Comment: you could put the empty check in your loop kill 2 birds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I do not agree with how you are doing this, a solution would be to add an error `array` to your first `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
     ${$key} = $_POST[$key];

     // If the field is empty, set an error
     if( empty($value) ) {
         $errors[] = 'Please enter a ' . $key . '.';
     }
}
```

And then change the bottom to check for the error `array`. If it's empty, run your code to complete the form submission. If not, loop through the errors.

```
if( empty($errors) ) {
    //code if all fields are not empty
}
else {
    // Loop through each error found
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use `$key` as well? I mean you only want to output the values right?

Comment: @Script47 correct, caught a quick typo - updated. Thanks :)

Comment: I wanted to store each inputted field into a variable for later a later date @Script47

Comment: @Dezmondeo but you would not need `$key` there. That is for the errors, and all you want to do is display the errors so the variable `key` is not required. You'd push the values of `$key` in the `if statement` where no errors have occurred.

Comment: This works perfectly, exactly what i wanted.  thanks  @RhapX

Comment: Ahh right I see what you mean, thanks a lot :) @Script47

Comment: @RhapX and Dezmondeo glad I could help.

Comment: @Script47 you are an actual legend, I really appreciate all your responses.